# New Systems Administrator

Tags: audit

I have had my own network setup running web sites for over two years now. Every once in a while strange things happen, but it's a easy fix (using no shortcuts) and majority of the time I just restore backups since I have pretty solid backups.

My question is, how easy is it for someone to break into my network via internet? I only have standard ports open (80, 443, 465 995) and (21, 22 LAN only open). When I look at my Gateway firewall for incoming traffic I see all kinds of connections, but nothing never seems to hit home. Virus scans show nothing has happened, tripwire is never reporting anything, and snort ; well just snorts I guess. How will I know when I am compromised?

Comment: Too few details but 80 and 443 are typical attack vectors for SQL injection, RFI, ... - i.e. web based attacks. And if the attacker is clever enough you will not easily notice.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the right things. You are reviewing logs, you have security measures in place and are checking them, and you know your potential attack surface. These are the things you need to be doing. You are ahead of some large, professional hosting companies, in this regard. It will be important that the logs you are collecting and reviewing are being stored on a log server, and not the web server.

But you asked two difficult questions. How easy is it to hack your network? That depends on the *services* you are running. Vulnerable, unpatched services, and poorly written and poorly secured websites are typically how people hack in. You need to look at hardening these things. That's an answer too big to be answered here (without narrowing it down).

Secondly, you asked how you would know your server has been compromised, and you are running the tools that would typically tell you (if logs are stored on a log server). That said, it is still possible for someone to compromise your server and you still wouldn't know about it. Stay alert and aware, and keep eyes on your servers. Learn new ways to detect new attacks and continually improve your detection and prevention methods.

This is far from a full answer, especially given how little info you provide, but you have a great start. Just realize that it is a start of a journey of protection.